# symbols named incompatibly in shared objects - where to look for problems

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, shared-libraries, libtool

I am new to Linux. I have access to two Linux machine, one 40 core server(A) and a cluster(B). I am trying to do the same on both machines, it works on A and doesn't on B. I have sudo rights on neither. A runs on debian squeeze/sid. B runs on kernel 2.6.18-238.el5. I could not find any release info file under /etc. A has gcc 4.6.2, whereas B gcc 4.1.2.

I compiled and installed locally on both machines a given meshing software Pkg1, and Pkg2, a given solver. Both need Libtool and automake. Pkg2 is a .so file. All work fine, I could run the examples. The code was built with mpicxx. Both have different mpi compilers. A uses openmpi154, B uses qlogicmpi_gnu-0.1.0.

Now I introduce my code, say Pkg3, a few .cpp files. I built a .so out of it. I did not use Libtool and automake. A simple make file, with gcc as compiler and linker (also tried mpicxx) was used.

On A, Pkg3 runs fine. On B, Pkg3 crashes. It crashes when it tries to dynamically cast some type in Pkg3 to a type defined in Pkg2 with message St8bad_cast. For another data file, it crashes when a function in Pkg2 tries to cast a type from Pkg3, with message 'element type is N5ngfem8FE_Segm2E expected type is N5ngfem19ScalarFiniteElementILi1EEE '

Where do I look for problems?  Sorry for being vague. All the software here is opensource, but the packages are too big to make a self contained repro with little amount of work. I have neither worked with automake and Libtools, nor with mpi yet, which compounds the issue. I looked into the makefiles of Pkg1 and Pkg2 and tried to map the CXX, LDFLAGS etc with my simple makefile, but the multiple indirections created by automake/libtools makes it difficult.

I understand the symbols in Pkg2 are mangled differently in the symbol table than the ones in Pkg3. But that should have been taken care of the linker?! I have tried with both with and without '-Wl,-E' options for Pkg3.  -fPIC is always there. The rule to link Pkg3, points to library Pkg2 (). I have posted the body of Pkg3's makefile.

```
 %.o : %.cpp
     gcc  -O2 -fopenmp -fPIC -DNETGEN_ELTRANS -DUSE_TIMEOFDAY -DLAPACK -I. -I$(NETGENDIR)/../include -c $? -o $@

 libmyngsolve.so : $(objects)
      gcc -shared -Wl,-E -fopenmp -fPIC $(objects) -L/home/lv70227/elan/ng/lib -lngsolve -o $@

 clean:
     rm *.o libmyngsolve.so
```

#### Note 1:

The `./configure` command for Pkg2 has `-Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64  -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -Wl,--end-group -lpthread`
i.e., it does not have -E flag. But that is how it was specified to me, as reference.

#### Note 2:

The path defined in the link rule, -L/home/lv70227/elan/ng/lib,
has pkg2.so.0.0.0, two symbolic links to it, and pkg2.la, not pkg2.sa since it was created by libtools.

Any hint as to where the problem could lie is appreciated. I have followed the same procedure on both machine, making minimum deviations to accommodate the different mpi, gcc, mkl libraries installed in A and B.

Thank you,
Elan.

Comment: You could consider building on machine *B* a recent *GCC 4.6* compiler (from its source code), and possibly building other software. You don't need root priviledge to build free software (perhaps thru `configure --prefix=$HOME`)

Comment: Please edit your question to format it more appropriately: you can show your source code or just your commands more nicely.

Comment: There is a big difference (notably in mangling and standard library API) between GCC 4.1. and GCC 4.6, especially with *C++* code!

Comment: Thank you Basile for your response. I did struggle with formatting that I copy pasted. I will also see if I can point to some particular error message.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in comments, GCC 4.1 and GCC 4.6 are so different that a possible solution could be to install a GCC 4.6 (perhaps by compiling its source code, and required dependencies) on your older machine.